# Adding a template to React Component

Tags: meteor-accounts

Im using the login example from the Meteor React Tutorial

```
meteor add accounts-ui accounts-password
```

Its all ok but Im trying to find the file and change it but I dont know where is it.

This is my code:

```
    import { Blaze } from 'meteor/blaze';

export default class AccountsUIWrapper extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
  }

  render(){
    return <span ref="container"/>
  }
}
```

And i have installed `meteor add useraccounts:materialize`

How can I put the template on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your component inside `/imports/ui/` directory and name the file as `AccountsUIWrapper.jsx`

So it will be saved as `/imports/ui/AccountsUIWrapper.jsx`.

Then you can import your wrapped component inside `/imports/ui/App.jsx` file with:

```
import AccountsUIWrapper from './AccountsUIWrapper.jsx';
```

And then use it in your React render function in the same file as:

```
<AccountsUIWrapper />
```

The tutorial lays it out [pretty clearly](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/adding-user-accounts), including all the filenames and locations. You should be able to access their GitHub repository for the same.

If you want, for reference, you can also take a look at [my code](https://github.com/NiveditN/meteor-todos-react/commit/00733fce05adf97cb5998131f9358ac00bb00bd6) at this particular step back when when I did this tutorial myself.

**Update: For useraccounts:materialize**

The `useraccounts:materialize` package that you have mentioned [depends on](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/materialize) `useraccounts:core` package as its base. So you cannot apply `useraccounts:materialize` to default meteor `accounts` package directly.

Follow the instructions on [useraccounts:core](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/core) to set it up. You may need to remove `accounts-ui` as well, as it would likely clash with the above packages.

Then, go through the [documentation](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md) for `useraccounts` that shows how to render their accounts template in Blaze.

After that, using the same way as shown in the tutorial, you should be able to create a new React wrapper for `useraccounts:materialize` Blaze template.

Here are links to boilerplate `useraccounts:materialize` code for Iron Router and Flow Router. From these you can take reference for the Blaze template code, which you can then wrap in React:

- [Boilerplate with iron:router](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/boilerplates/tree/master/materialize-iron-router)
- [Boilerplate with FlowRouter](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/boilerplates/tree/master/materialize-flow-router)

Comment: Yes but where I should indicate the style to uses a template? like this:
https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/materialize

Comment: Im tried to remove usseraccounts-ui but i get an error

Comment: It's accounts-ui, not useraccounts-ui. Try 'meteor remove accounts-ui'.

Comment: Ok thanks now its deleted, i will try to use a custom templete, im using react router ^^Thanks for the info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122254/discussion-between-pcg26-and-nivedit).